# 4.7.3 wordpress menu shows horizontally

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I downloaded latest wordpress yeaterday. The menu in admin panel are now arranged horizontally and it's difficult to arrange with sub menus.

I created custom theme then found no menu option under the APPEARENCE. So I added the below code in functions.php

```
//add menu option in the admin panel sidebar APPEARENCE
function wpb_custom_new_menu() {

  register_nav_menu('main-navigation',__( 'Main Navigation' ));
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );
```

Now the menu option added, but it looks weird as attached.
[image]

**Is there any way to arrange it back to vertical?**

Answer (score 0):

Please check the li style of the menu if float is assign then remove it or add css like below snippet.

```css
ul.primarymenu li{
display:block;
padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="primarymenu">
<li>menu1</li>
<li>menu2</li>
<li>menu3</li>
<li>menu4</li>
</ul>
```